# How to Create AVD on version 4.0 APi 14 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

in Eclipse, I have installed the latest version Android 5.0.1(API 21) and created an AVD. However to test backward compatibility I need to create an AVD for older Android 4.0 (API 14), which is also installed in Eclipse. However, when go open Andriod AVD Manager and say create, in the Target pulldown menu, I do not see Android 4.0 (API 14) and therefore unable to create a AVD to support Android 4.0 (API 14). Can someone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: Check if API 14 still exist in your SDK manager or not

Comment: First, from the **Packages** menu (in the _SDK Manager_), check the option _Show Obsolete Packages_. This will display the API 14 for you. Then, install the API 14 SDK Platform. If this is already done, check if you have at least one system image for API 14 installed. If not, install one from the SDK Manager. Then you can create an AVD for the API level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check whether Google API 14 in installed on your device.

Click Android SDK Manager, u can see SDK Manager, u can see Android 4.0(API 14) u can see **Google APIs should be installed** then only u can install the AVD otherwise u cannot create a AVD

If you want to create an AVD in Eclipse you need to do this:

Go to Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager

Then you need to give a name and select the platform that you want (Target option)

Then the button "Create AVD" activates.

The other options modify if u need

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps:
**1.** Open SDK Manager as this screen:
[image]

You must install SDK, Arm system image or Intel system image whose version as you need (mine is 21 and you is 14) for run emulator

**2.** Open AVD Manager and click "Create"

[image]

**3.** enter name, choose target and other properties. Then you have your emulator

[image]
**Hope this help! And dont foget to mark this is answer if you archived your goal!**